# ul li specific positioning

Tags: html, css

I need my links positioned to the right of the second photo (opus1) and a little under the first photo(coverPhoto). So really I just need my links positioned to the right side. I've tried going about this in a number of different ways, and I'm sure it's a simple solution, but I'm stumped.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Opus</title>
    <link href="opus.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <div class="logo">
    <img class="coverPhoto" src="images/coverPhoto.jpg" alt="Cover Photo" height="300" width="1330">
    <img src="images/opus1.jpg" alt="Logo" height="500" width="600">
    </div>

 <body>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="home"><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
            <li id="about"><a href="#"> About</a></li>
            <li id="more"><a href="#"> More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 </body>

 </head>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(104, 0, 1);
}

#home {

}

#about {

}

#more {

}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a JS fiddle or some sort of visual representations of the working code for us to fiddle with?

Comment: In your `html`, your `</head>` (and then `<body>`) should follow your stylesheet `<link>` element.

Answer (score 0):

1) Nest the `<div class="nav">` inside the `<div class="logo">`:

```
<div class="logo">

<img class="coverPhoto" src="images/coverPhoto.jpg" alt="Cover Photo" height="300" width="1330">
<img src="images/opus1.jpg" alt="Logo" height="500" width="600">

<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li id="home"><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
<li id="about"><a href="#"> About</a></li>
<li id="more"><a href="#"> More</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

2) Display both the images and the `<div class="nav">` as `inline-block`s and apply a left `float` to each:

```
img, .nav {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
```